# SF paperback about small devil like creatures unearthed by a farmer

Tags: story-identification, horror

Around 1972 I read a sf paperback about small devil like creatures unearthed by a farmer. He thought they were rabbits before they attacked him. The creatures killed and ate everything until the food source ran out, then they turned on each other.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not Edmund Cooper's [*Kronk*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0340162171) , but the scene you describe reminds me of this scene from *Kronk:*

ch. Twenty-Five:

> But the rest of the rabbits did not seem to care. It was all part of
>   the show. They swarmed all over him, so that he looked like a
>   seething, writhing, screaming mountain of palpitating fur. They kicked
>   him and scratched him and bit him and stamped upon him. And within
>   less than a minute, while a few brave NaTel souls were clubbing
>   peripheral attackers with vids, tripods and any items of equipment
>   that were handy, the mad rabbits of Yorkshire had kicked a still
>   incredulous Uncle Dan to death.

Comment: It's probably not _[Monty Python's Quest for the Holy Grail](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcxKIJTb3Hg)_ either...